# Upload image from imageview

Tags: java, parse-platform

Hello please help me have need upload current image in image view

I have need upload the image capture in telephone
    `public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button button;
    private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888;
    private ImageView imageView;

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // Get the view from main.xml
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    }
```

// Locate the button in main.xml
        button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadbtn);

```
    // Capture button clicks
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // Locate the image in res > drawable-hdpi
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.drawable.androidbegin);
            // Convert it to byte
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            // Compress image to lower quality scale 1 - 100
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte[] image = stream.toByteArray();

            // Create the ParseFile
            ParseFile file = new ParseFile("androidbegin.png", image);
            // Upload the image into Parse Cloud
            file.saveInBackground();

            // Create a New Class called "ImageUpload" in Parse
            ParseObject imgupload = new ParseObject("ImageUpload");

            // Create a column named "ImageName" and set the string
            imgupload.put("ImageName", "AndroidBegin Logo");

            // Create a column named "ImageFile" and insert the image
            imgupload.put("ImageFile", file);

            // Create the class and the columns
            imgupload.saveInBackground();

            // Show a simple toast message
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image Uploaded",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}`

Comment: What's the problem here, dasa?

Comment: i have need change // Create the ParseFile
            ParseFile file = new ParseFile("androidbegin.png", image);
            // Upload the image into Parse Cloud
            file.saveInBackground(); whit image view current

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you just do most of the work on the onActivityResult method?

```
Button take_picture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.addPicButton);
    take_picture.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dispatchTakePictureIntent();
        }
    });

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
byte[] image_byte_array;
if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
    ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    photo.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
    image_byte_array = stream.toByteArray();
    imageView.setImageBitmap(photo);
    ParseFile pf = new ParseFile("Picture", image_byte_array);
    pf.saveInBackground();
}
```

I messed around with parse for a while and made an app, check this repo out... maybe youl find some useful code. https://github.com/Aquaballin/HackingVeggies/tree/master/ProduceList/src/com/parse/starter

good luck bro!

Comment: Okay I made an edit, you should be able to see the files in parse with this, definitely how I was able to upload parse files to my tables. Let me know if that helps. Perhaps using the camera api methods and overriding them will  help

Comment: ok, thanks now upload done, can help me for share image view?

Comment: how do you want to share it? and can you up vote my answer so that people can use this code in the future? Thanks, ill try my best to help you with that next